# What does "set -t" do in bash?

Tags: bash

I've tried testing this but it doesn't seem to work the way the manual says it does - from `help set`:

> -t  Exit after reading and executing one command.

I tried a couple of different tests:

For this one there was *no* output to the terminal

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -t

echo "test"
```

For this one running it and then running `echo $TEST_VAR` from the terminal shows `$TEST_VAR` is empty

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -t

export TEST_VAR="test"
```

What does `set -t` really do and what is an example of how it can be used?

Comment: [invoking bash with the -t option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/119885/74329)

Comment: Running `export` (or any other assignment in a subshell) **never** changes variables in the parent-process shell, so testing `$TEST_VAR` in the terminal of the invoking shell is not particularly meaningful -- you'd get identical behavior anywhere, regardless of `-t` or any other flag set after the script is invoked in a `fork()`ed-off child process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`set -t` causes bash to immediately exit, because it becomes the *one command* being read and executed before exiting. it was probably meant to be used for creating a temporary shell. for an example of where it's used see the [question @Cyrus posted in comments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/119885/invoking-bash-with-the-t-option).

Answer (score 0):

> For this one running it and then running echo $TEST_VAR from the
>   terminal shows $TEST_VAR is empty
>
> #!/usr/bin/env bash
>
> set -t
>
> export TEST_VAR="test"

of course, as it's in another environment when you reopen new terminal
it's done and apply only on its first terminal environment.. prove it;

```
set -t;>test
```

Reopen terminal and it'll be new `test` file